# Javascript Conditions are Executing Either Way

Tags: javascript

please help me out on this, I realy don't figure out where is the problem.
my code:

```
function validateForm()
{
    var pic = document.getElementById("photo1").value;
    pic = pic.split('/').pop().split('\\').pop().replace(/[.][^.]+$/, "");
    var x = document.getElementById("gyuruszam");
    var gyuru = document.getElementById("gyuruszam").value;
    if (gyuru == null || gyuru == "" || gyuru == " ")
    {
        alert("Gyűrűszám nélkül nem lehet adatot lementeni!");
        x.focus();
        x.style.borderColor="#C30";
        return false;
    }
    if ((gyuru != pic) && (pic != NULL)){
        alert("A kép neve nem egyezik meg a gyűrűszámal!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I don't know why is executing the second `if`, if I do not select file on the field.
I just want an `if` condition, if I select file and the `gyuru` is not equal with the name of the file, then return false with an error message. But if I don't select a file return true(ornot even entering in the loop)
Thank you in advance!
EDIT:
I also try this way:

```
function validateForm()
{
    var pic = document.getElementById("photo1").value;
    pic = pic.split('/').pop().split('\\').pop().replace(/[.][^.]+$/, "");
    var x = document.getElementById("gyuruszam");
    var gyuru = document.getElementById("gyuruszam").value;
    if (gyuru == null || gyuru == "" || gyuru == " ")
    {
        alert("Gyűrűszám nélkül nem lehet adatot lementeni!");
        x.focus();
        x.style.borderColor="#C30";
        return false;
    }
    else if ((gyuru != pic) && (pic != NULL)){
        alert("A kép neve nem egyezik meg a gyűrűszámal!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

it's working, but not like I want, because if I upload a file with different name, not equal with `gyuru` it's return true.
my form data is:

```
<form...
<input type="text" id="gyuruszam" name="gyuruszam"/>
<input type="file" id="photo1" name="photo1"/>
../form>
```

AND i CHECK THE RETURNED FILE NAME `pic` IT'S CORRECT!

Comment: Can you provide the html as well?

Comment: Just on a side note, it's best practice when comparing with null you should use ===, instead of ==, also 'NULL' will throw you an error, change that to null

Comment: Yep, other best practice is to put the "constant" first, `null === myVariable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry I'm not sure of what you want.
Your code has a mistake, `NULL` does not exists, you should put `null`.
Second problem: `pic` cannot be null, it will be an empty string if you don't select a file.

So I guess you are looking for:

```
} else if ((gyuru != pic) && (pic != null) && (pic != '')) {
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/nyothecat/ALjGJ/

Comment: thank you very much, yes, you're right about the `pic` it cannot be `null`! I don't know why I did not remark that before...
Thank's again very much!